# NSButton is highlighted after setTransparent:NO setEnabled:YES

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I have 2 `NSButton`s, both are bordered momentary push-in buttons. I have a main window to which other views are swapped in and out. These two buttons are in the main window custom view (next,previous) which helps to navigate through the views.

When I reach the 2 view with the help of next button, I make the previous button enabled and visible. So if I press the previous button at this point the 1st view will be swapped in and I make the previous button transparent and enabled.

At this point if you press the next button to navigate to second view, the 2nd view will be swapped in and the previous button is displayed again. But it is **highlighted here**. How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you will get some better answers, but a general technique that I have found to work in cases like this is to wait with enable/disable actions until things have settled down for the new configuration of the views.

After all (if I have read your description correctly), you are hiding a button in the middle of its own action handler.

Postponing this is easily obtained by dispatching your enable/disable code on the next (or, more correctly, a later) invocation of the run loop of the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    // Enable or disable your buttons here.
});
```

As a solution it is somewhat of a hack, but on the other hand, waiting until your main view is no longer in a state of flux before you re-configure your navigation UI is not a bad approach.